# What is "Integer.valueOf().intValue()" supposed to do?

Tags: java

Here is a java line of code that i have failed to understand.

```
 String line = "Some data";//I understand this line
 int size;//I understand this line too

 size = Integer.valueOf(line,16).intValue();//Don't understand this one
```

What i know is **Integer.ValueOf(line**) is the same as **Integer.parseInt(line)** , is not so? Correct me if i am wrong; Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean `Integer.valueOf`, btw - lower case `V`.

Comment: Yes i mean Integer.valueOf()!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Integer.ValueOf(line,16)` converts string value `line` into an `Integer` object. In this case radix is 16.

`intValue()` gets the `int` value from the `Integer`  `object` created above.

Furthermore, above two steps are  equivalent to `Integer.parseInt(line,16)`.

In order to get more INFO please refer Java API Documentation of [Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class.

Comment: Radix is the base of a number system. For example in decimal system radix is ten, in binary system radix is two.

Comment: I'm sorry,yes It should be radix

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is equivalent to:

```
size = Integer.parseInt(line, 16);
```

Indeed, looking at the implementation, the existing code is actually implemented as effectively:

```
size = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(line, 16)).intValue();
```

which is clearly pointless.

The assignment to -1 in the previous line is pointless, by the way. It would only be relevant if you could still read the value if an exception were thrown by `Integer.parseInt`, but as the scope of `size` is the same block as the call to `Integer.valueof`, it won't be in scope after an exception anyway.

Comment: U're right, i should remove the -1 assignment for the sake of making the code easier to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the data type of the variables on the left hand side.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "CAFE";
        Integer m = Integer.valueOf(s, 16);
        int n = m.intValue();

        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

`Integer` is a reference type that wraps `int`, which is a primitive type.

Comment: Your meaning is **Integer m** (reference type) contains **int n** (primitive type),right?

Comment: **m** contains an `int` primitive type but it is not contain **n**.

Answer (score -1):

```
" = Integer.valueOf().intValue()"
```

and Example:

```
String myNumber = "54";    
int c = Integer.valueOf(myNumber).intValue();  // convert strings to numbers
```

result:

```
54 // like int (and before was a String)
```